# Forge viewer Display anomaly

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a situation where two construction models are loaded in the viewer.
The stair model is moved (whith placement transform) in the building model.
The stair model is now obscured by the building model also behind glass elements
[see this gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oimoX.gif)

Depending on the camera position the stair is visible again.
Viewer is 7.38.1

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when a model is loaded, the opaque objects are rendered first and the transparent objects are rendered last. If you are loading the first model which contains the transparent objects and then the stair model, the transparent objects might be rendering before the stair model. This might be causing this issue.

I would suggest trying the following: load the stair model first and then the model with the transparent objects. If the above statement is correct, this might fix the issue.

In any case, It would be useful to get the repro steps for this and maybe the model assets.

Last, are you using AggregatedView or are you loading the models using Viewer3D#loadModel?

We logged the issue as LMV-5962

Comment: I loaded the stair model first, as soon as I orbit arround, the stair disappears.
The user can select different models from a tree, so no control on what they pick first.
Placement transform values are read from a database prior to loading the model in the viewer.
we use aggregate view .setNodes(bubbles)
getCustomLoadOptions.placementTransform to place the models relevant to each other.
If you need the assets let me know how to send them to you